# How to add parameters in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to add a customised alert box in javascript. I have sample code for a customised alert box in javascript but it displays a static message (that was given in the function), I want to dynamically change the title and message. Please show me where to add title and message parameter in this `#alert_button` function .

```
/*
    jQuery document ready
    You can also drag custom box.
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#alert_button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        /*
            jAlert is function which will show custom alert.
                It has two argument.
            First argument is content for alert.
                Second is the Alert heading .
        */
        jAlert('title', 'message');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: How do you want to dynamically change the message?

Comment: From where do you want to get `title` and `message`?

Comment: by passing two parameters(title,message) to alert_button function

Comment: Where is alert_button function?

Comment: But how will you supply the values in a click handler?  You could set some data- attributes on the button beforehand I guess - or source the text from javascript global variables / or another control.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can store `data` for any dom element, so you can store `titles` and `messages` in your buttons and access them inside your 'click' event (or any other) listener function like this:

```
$("#alert_button").data({title: 'some title', message: 'some message'});
$("#alert_button").click( function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    /*
        jAlert is function which will show custom alert.
        It has two argument.
        First argument is content for alert.
        Second is the Alert heading .
    */

    jAlert($(e.target).data().title, $(e.target).data().message);
});
```

Comment: Didn't know about `data`, thanks! Need to investigate is it gets cleared on changing, variables stay in memory, changing DOM element recreates it in some cases. Anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

Use variables to achieve that.

```
var prop_title = 'title',
    prop_message = 'message',
    condition = true;

$("#alert_button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    jAlert(prop_title, prop_message);
});

if (condition) {
    prop_message = 'Message is changed now';
}
```

Changing `prop_title` & `prop_message` respectivley will affect what will be showed, as `jAlert` function binded in `click` event takes it's attributes from those variables.

Change your `condition` as you wish in your code or create new ones to differ messages.

Here you can test that http://jsfiddle.net/60y4hmuc/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want JAlert title and message dynamicly set.

If JAlert is only triggered by clicking on single element ($("#alert_button") is as ID single element)) then I see no point of dynamically assigning values.

If your idea is to use JAlert for multiple elements (like $(".alert_button") (so using class and having multiple elements that can be clickable)) - you can use additional attributes with those elements and just call them as variables in JAlert - so for example:

```
<button id="alert_button1" class="alert_button" title="Title in alert1" data-message="Message in alert1">alert button 1"</button>

<button id="alert_button2" class="alert_button" title="Title in alert2" data-message="Message in alert2">alert button 2"</button>
```

...

and in function just write something that:

- get's current clicked element's title adn data-message as variables
- trigger JAlert with those variables